# What is the name of the Automator application process?

Tags: macos, automator, activity-monitor

I want to kill the process of the Automator application, but i can't find the name of it in the activity monitor.

Comment: What problem are you having that you need to kill Automator?

Comment: Welcome to the community.  The process you are looking for is 'Automator'. Sometimes things are easy to miss, so open your activity monitor and look for it. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Automator.app's main process is called "Automator".

[image]

You should be able to Force Quit it from the Apple menu, or from right-clicking its Dock icon.

Of course, Automator workflows that are still running will be entirely separate processes.

Comment: Hmm, that was also my first guess, but there is no process called Automator in my Activity Monitor.In the Dock there is no "dot" under the Automator icon, so it seems Automator is not started, but i can not open it and a right click on the icon shows "App is frozen"..

Comment: @tbr Have you tried Force Quitting from the methods I mentioned? Is the problem that Automator won't launch?

Comment: @tbr If all else fails, restart the computer.

Comment: i have already tried "force quit" but it is not working. i think automator is running, because i get the message in the dock "force quit" and "app is frozen"...

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an AppleScript a while back which helped me address the same kind of issue you are dealing with. In short, the code gives the options to choose from either visible or invisible application processes, in which you want killed.  The code then uses the shell script command `kill` to terminate those processes by their process ID.

The advantage to using this rather than Activity Monitor is that this code allows for selecting multiple items or processes to kill in one shot.  Activity Monitor only allows for selecting one process at a time.

With your circumstance, I would run this code and first choose to view the list of visible applications.  If Automator is not in that list, I would choose to kill Finder in that list (which will kill Finder and relaunch it). Then check to see if that solves your problem. If not, then run the script again and choose to view the list of invisible application processes, selecting "WorkflowServiceRunner" (if it exists), "System Events", and "System UI Server" and kill those processes (which should kill them and relaunch them also)

You can run this following code directly in Script Editor.app or save the code  in Script Editor.app as an application and just like any other app in Finder,  just double click the file to launch it.

```
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

property appsToKill : missing value
property NSArray : a reference to current application's NSArray

activate
set theChoice to button returned of (display dialog ¬
    "WOULD YOU LIKE TO LIST VISIBLE OR INVISIBLE APP PROCESSES?" buttons ¬
    {"CANCEL", "VISIBLE", "INVISIBLE"} default button ¬
    "INVISIBLE" cancel button "CANCEL" with title ¬
    "  WOULD YOU LIKE TO LIST VISIBLE OR INVISIBLE APP PROCESSES?  " with icon ¬
    2 giving up after 10)

if theChoice is "INVISIBLE" then
    listInvisibleAppProcesses(false)
else if theChoice is "VISIBLE" then
    listInvisibleAppProcesses(true)
else if theChoice is "CANCEL" then
    return
else if theChoice is "" then
    return
end if

set aList to ((NSArray's arrayWithArray:appsToKill)'s ¬
    sortedArrayUsingSelector:"caseInsensitiveCompare:") as list

activate
set killApp to (choose from list ¬
    aList with title "Choose The App To Kill" with prompt ¬
    "Choose The App" OK button name "OK" cancel button name ¬
    "CANCEL" with multiple selections allowed)

set pidList to {}

if killApp is not false then
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat with i from 1 to count of killApp
            set thisItem to item i of killApp
            tell application process thisItem
                set thePID to unix id
                set end of pidList to thePID
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
else
    return
end if

set text item delimiters to space
do shell script ({"kill", pidList} as text)

on listInvisibleAppProcesses(trueOrFalse)
    tell application "System Events"
        set appsToKill to name of every application process ¬
            where visible is trueOrFalse
    end tell
end listInvisibleAppProcesses
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Hopefully this will help with your situation but if it doesn't, saving this code as an application in Script Editor.app  and using it rather than Activity Monitor... To kill applications...  Should prove to be a handy tool in your arsenal.

Comment: Nice script. Some minor suggestions to consider, none critical: ➀ Avoid top-level globals for good practice. Here, it’s only set once, so probably better done in the two `then` clauses, `if theChoice...then... set appsToKill to listInvisibleAppProcesses(…)`. ➁ Iterating `pidList` can be replaced by setting TIDs to `space` then `do shell script ({"kill", i} as text)`. ➂ Doubt `activate` is useful. Check "Results" in Script Editor to see who receives command, but pretty sure it’ll be `current application`/`Script Editor`. ➃ You may prefer `"caseInsensitiveCompare:"`. Anyway, +1.

Comment: Thanks for your script, really cool! Unfortunately it doesn't help with my problem, the Automator App is still frozen. I think i have to reboot the mac.

Comment: @CJK  Removing the top level variable `global appsToKill` and trying to set its value in the 2 `then` clauses with `set appsToKill to listInvisibleAppProcesses(…)` threw an error.  Removing the top level variable `global appsToKill` and replacing it with `property appsToKill : missing value` , seems to work without a hitch.  Iterating `pidList` was successfully replaced by setting TIDs to space then `do shell script ({"kill", pidList} as text)` after I replaced (your suggestion of) `i` with `pidList`.

Comment: @CJK ... Continued... And yes the `activate` command while running the code directly from Script Editor.app, targets Script Editor.  Excerpted from Learn AppleScript 3rd Edition.pdf, "When writing AppleScript applets that display dialog boxes to users, you may want the applet to send an activate command to itself immediately before it displays a dialog box: ... That way, your applet will bring itself to the front, ensuring that the user doesn’t miss the dialog box."

Comment: _"after I replaced (your suggestion of) `I` with `pidList`"_ Oops, apologies. Since I'm idling currently in an Apple Store, I quickly threw you (latest version) script into _Script Editor_. Removing the property declaration for `appsToKill` and simply setting the variable as I previously described didn't produce any errors. I can only surmise that you made some small error, such as a typo. Without knowing the error message, I can only offer reassurance that it does work as one would expect.

Comment: Regarding `activate`, as it applies _only_ to an script running as an applet (which I would imagine is not the average case at all), I would strongly recommend having the script presented without these types of additional sugar coatings, that can be very suitably added as a final note that illustrates where to insert the `activate` command and what situation one would benefit from doing this (and how, of course).  It will help minimise the newbies picking up habits like inserting an `activate` command before every line, which I've seen before.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fantastic concept! A couple of minor suggestions (albeit nearly 3 years late):

- The original script didn't provide a method for handling multiple instances of the same App Process. Instead, it would only kill the first in its list of PIDs. An alternative I'm suggesting is to:

  1. shorten the list of invisibles for easier scrolling and selection
  2. add & kill full PID list of each multi-instance process

```
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

property appsToKill : missing value
property NSArray : a reference to current application's NSArray

activate
set theChoice to button returned of (display dialog ¬
    "Would you like to list Visible or Invisible App Processes?" buttons ¬
    {"Cancel", "Visible", "Invisible"} default button ¬
    "Invisible" cancel button "Cancel" with icon ¬
    2 giving up after 10)

if theChoice is "Invisible" then
    listInvisibleAppProcesses(false)
else if theChoice is "Visible" then
    listInvisibleAppProcesses(true)
else if theChoice is "Cancel" then
    return
else if theChoice is "" then
    return
end if

set aList to ((NSArray's arrayWithArray:appsToKill)'s ¬
    sortedArrayUsingSelector:"caseInsensitiveCompare:") as list

(*
shortening the list by removing duplicate entries 
    (as the original code did not differentiate between instances and in fact only killed first in the list regardless of selection) *)
if theChoice is "Invisible" then
    set {aList, bList} to removeDuplicateItems(aList)
else
    set bList to {}
end if


activate
set killApp to (choose from list ¬
    aList with title "Choose The App(s) To Kill" with prompt ¬
    "Choose The App(s)" OK button name "OK" cancel button name ¬
    "Cancel" with multiple selections allowed)

set pidList to {}

if killApp is not false then
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat with i from 1 to count of killApp
            set thisItem to item i of killApp
            tell application process thisItem
                if thisItem is in bList then
                    -- if there are multiple instances of thisItem, add PID of each to pidList
                    set name_pid to paragraphs of (do shell script "ps -A | grep " & quoted form of thisItem & " | awk {'print$1'}") as list
                    set namepid to {}
                    repeat with aPid in name_pid
                        set end of namepid to aPid as integer
                    end repeat
                else
                    set namepid to unix id
                end if
                set pidList to pidList & namepid
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
else
    return
end if

set text item delimiters to space
do shell script ({"kill", pidList} as text)

on listInvisibleAppProcesses(trueOrFalse)
    tell application "System Events"
        set appsToKill to name of every application process ¬
            where visible is trueOrFalse
    end tell
end listInvisibleAppProcesses

on removeDuplicateItems(inputList)
    set outputList to {}
    set dupeList to {}
    repeat with anItem in inputList
        set itemCont to contents of anItem as text
        if outputList does not contain itemCont then
            copy itemCont to end of the outputList
        else
            if dupeList does not contain itemCont then
                copy itemCont to end of the dupeList
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
    return {outputList, dupeList}
end removeDuplicateItems
```